# I am trying to add hours and minutes to a date to display a new date and time

Tags: python-3.x

I have looked and tried everything. I am a student and this is a homework assignment but I cannot figure out how to add the time to the date. I am trying to get the arrival date and time, by adding the hours and minutes it took to get there to the departure time, but it keeps adding days and second. This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import locale

def get_departure_date():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD:)")
        try:
            departure_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again.")
            continue
        now = datetime.now()
        today = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
        if departure_date < today:
            print("Departure date must be today or later. Try again")
            continue
        else:
            return departure_date
def get_departure_time():
    while True:
        time_str = input("Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM:)")
        try:
            departure_time = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%I:%M %p")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invaild time format. Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            return departure_time
def get_miles():
    while True:
        try:
            miles = int(input("Enter miles:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Integer. Please try again.")
            continue
        else:
            return miles
def get_mph():
    while True:
        try:
            mph = int(input("Enter miles per hour:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Integer. Please try again.")
            continue
        else:
            return mph



def main():
    print("Arrival Time Estimator")
    print()
    while True:
        departure_date = get_departure_date()
        departure_time = get_departure_time()
        miles = get_miles()
        mph = get_mph()
        hours = int(miles // mph)
        minutes = int(miles - (60 * hours))
        arrival_date = departure_date + timedelta(hours, minutes)
        print("hours: ", hours)
        print("minutes: ", minutes)
        print (arrival_date)
        print()


        result = input("Continue?  (y/n):  ")
        print()
        if result.lower() != "y":
            print("Bye!")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timedelta` constructor is not really intuitive in my mind. I find it's easiest to use with named arguments.

Change this line:

```
arrival_date = departure_date + timedelta(hours, minutes)
```

To this:

```
arrival_date = departure_date + timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)
```